# How iterate pandas dataframe if condition is met then add new rows to df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate each row of df2['name]' if the coin name is also found in df1 I want to  create a new row in df2 with the tag names of df1. Alternatively create a new Df3 which ever the easiest.

I have tried many solution such as iterating but I had no luck

```
for row in df2['name']:
  
   for row2 in df1['name']:
   
      if row == row2:
        ...cannot complete this step...
```

My main issue it is that I don't know what is the best methodology to approach this. Iterations or not? I am sure that pandas has a better method but I cannot work it out.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like that

df1

|  | name | tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bitcoin | mineable |
| 2 | ethereum | pow |

and a second one like this

df2

|  | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bitcoin | 0 |
| 2 | ethereum | 0.242424 |

Df3 the one I want to create

|  | name | value | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bitcoin | 0 | mineable |
| 2 | ethereum | 0.242424 | pow |

Comment: Hello, instead of iterating, you can use ```pandas.merge``` to join dataframes based on defined key which is ```name``` in your case. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#inner-join

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""name  tags
bitcoin     mineable
ethereum    pow"""), sep="\s+")


df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""name  value
bitcoin     0
ethereum    0.242424"""), sep="\s+")

>>> df1.merge(df2, on="name")
       name      tags     value
0   bitcoin  mineable  0.000000
1  ethereum       pow  0.242424
```